# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'weight'

Tags: python, bigdata, data-preprocessing

So I am trying to make a dictionary from a csv, the first head of the csv contains 2 header, one for the word and one for the weight of the word. But everytime I try to read it, it always give the value error when I tried to make it read the string by changing it to int(str(row[1])). And that didn't work, I am really confused on how to make this dictionary

positive_dictionary.py

```
lexicon_positive = dict()
import csv
with open('Lexicon/positive.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        lexicon_positive[row[0]] = int(row[1])
```

Lexicon/positive.csv

```
word,weight
hi,3
record,2
extensive,3
plenary,1
detail,2
```

Comment: you need to handle column header as well while using csv.reader

Comment: check out the CSV module's [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)